# vertically align top line of item contents with item number

Tags: vertical-alignment, align, enumerate

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item This looks good.
    \item
      $\begin{aligned}
        \mathrm{This} &= \mathrm{is} \\
                      &= \mathrm{not\ nicely\ aligned}
      \end{aligned}$
    \item \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            & Neither & is \\
       this & table.  &    \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}
```

It currently looks like this:

[image]

But I want it to look like this:

[image]

Vertically-aligned so that the top line of the ... item contents, lines up with the item number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item This looks good.
    \item
      $\begin{aligned}[t]
        \mathrm{This} &= \mathrm{is} \\
                      &= \mathrm{not\ nicely\ aligned}
      \end{aligned}$
    \item \begin{tabular}[t]{ccc}
            & Neither & is \\
       this & table.  &    \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]